# Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$book_id

Tags: php, codeigniter

A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$book_id

```
 <th scope="row"><?php echo $row->book_id ?></th>
```

Comment: `print_r($prods)` check this before `foreach` loop and share the result

Comment: it seams like you don't have `book_id` column.

Comment: there is no `book_id` column, you can see it yourself if you `print_r($row);`

Comment: do not change your question, your original question looks fine. `https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54402842/1` you just need to debug `print_r($prods)`

Comment: second check your controller, are you loading your model before query execution? like `$this->load->model('your model');` ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that attribute does not exist in your object.

Use the below to see the attribute of the object:

```
var_dump($row);exit;
```